# Scala/Spark serializable error - join don't work

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, rdd

I am trying to use join method between 2 RDD and save it to cassandra but my code don't work . at the begining , i get a huge Main method and everything working well , but when i use function and class this don't work . i am new to scala and spark

code is :

```
  class Migration extends Serializable { 

  case class userId(offerFamily: String, bp: String, pdl: String) extends Serializable
  case class siteExternalId(site_external_id: Option[String]) extends Serializable
  case class profileData(begin_ts: Option[Long], Source: Option[String]) extends Serializable

  def SparkMigrationProfile(sc: SparkContext) = {

    val test  = sc.cassandraTable[siteExternalId](KEYSPACE,TABLE)
     .keyBy[userId]
     .filter(x => x._2.site_external_id != None)

    val profileRDD = sc.cassandraTable[profileData](KEYSPACE,TABLE)
    .keyBy[userId]

    //dont work
   test.join(profileRDD)
    .foreach(println)

    // don't work
     test.join(profileRDD)
     .saveToCassandra(keyspace, table)

   }
```

At the beginig i get the famous : Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable at . . .
so i extends my main class and also the case class but stil don't work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should move your case classes from `Migration` class to dedicated file and/or object. This should solve your problem. Additionally, Scala case classes are serializable by default.

Comment: it's working ! i fell so stupid now . . .
can you explain to me why ?

Comment: hi @user3394825, it's hard to say, because I haven't use Spark with Cassandra. Based on my experience I had similar issues when using case classes defined in other class. In your situation there could be some issue with creating implicit parameters for `cassandraTable` function (https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/SparkContextFunctions.scala) e.g. `rrf: RowReaderFactory[T],
ev: ValidRDDType[T]`, but I'm just guessing. I know that when using Spark SQL Encoder there is also similar exception.

Comment: The case classes are technically inner classes that have access to an enclosing instance of Migration. When they are serialized, the accompanying Migration object is also serialized. And even though it is marked Serializable, there is probably some instance variable somewhere within it that is not. Often the culprit is a SparkContext object.